# What is the smallest interval of positive real numbers containing a representative from each equivalence class?

Tags: terminology, relations, equivalence-relations

Let's define a relation $R$ on the $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers as follows:

For any elements $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, let's define $x R y$ to mean $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers.

This $R$ is indeed an equivalence relation and so partitions $\mathbb{R}$ into disjoint sets, called *equivalence classes*, where, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we define the equivalence class $[x]$ of $x$ as
$$[x] \colon= \left\{ \ y \in \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ y R x \ \right\} = \left\{ \ y \in \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ y - x \in \mathbb{Q} \ \right\}.$$

Can we characterize (any of) these equivalence classes as a countable set of points 
$$ \left\{ \ p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots \right\}?$$

Now let's form a set $S$ as follows: The set $S$ contains the smallest positive element of the equivalence classes $[ x ]$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then is this set $S$ bounded from above in $\mathbb{R}$? If so, then what is the supremum of $S$?

In particular, can we assume that $S$ is contained in $(0, 1)$? $(0, 1]$?

Is there a name for this particular equivalence relation in the standard mathematical literature?

Comment: The problem is that $\mathbb Q$ is one of the equivalence classes, and it has no smallest positive element. Neither do any of the other classes. They are all countable though, since they're all translates of $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Every one of the equivalence classes is countable.

I think you will have trouble defining your set $S$:

What is the smallest positive element in the equivalence class $\mathbb{Q}$ itself? If you think things through you will realize that none of the equivalence classes has a smallest positive element.

It is true that every class has many representatives in every interval. That's because you can approximate any real number arbitrarily well by rationals.

I don't know whether this relation has a standard name.

Answer (score 0):

As every non-trivial interval contains a representative
set, there is no such smallest interval.

Comment: @Leucippus  It answers the question in the title.